# Building an Restfull Api with Laravel 5

Tags: php, api, laravel

I'm planning to build an restfull api with laravel 5 for a client because they also want to make apps in the future (first ios/android, larer ios watch). For version 1.0 they only want a webversion of the site, so i'm planning to do that the traditional way with blade templating and laravel routing.

Are there good practices for combining those 2? The api routes will in some places be different then the routes i need for the 'normal' webversion, most of the services and repositories would also be the same. Output would to totally different because the api needs to return Json, where the 'normal' webversion would return Html.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would really consider not using Blade and using a front-end framework instead such as Angular.  If you can get to the point where your back-end is solely serving up JSON responses, it would make your life much easier down the road.

As an added benefit, a single page app would also be much more usable on a mobile device out of the box.

You could also look into PhoneGap as well.  If you have everything running on Angular, it shouldn't be too difficult to port it over to PhoneGap.

Comment: True. I also was considering doing that. But what about SEO in AngularJs? For SEO you need to return a server response for every page url, so thats also extra work.